# Modify elements of an array iterated with .each

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm using an .each loop to iterate over an array. I want to change elements in this array, so I tried something like this:

```
ex = ["el01", "el02", "el03", "el04"]
ex.each do |el|
    if (el == "el02")
        el = "changed"
    end
end
puts ex
```

but it seems don't works! It puts me :

```
el01
el02
el03
el04
```

I want to know what I did wrong! or if it can't be done this way, how to do it.

Comment: if you googled this up you would have got thousand of answers, you clearly don't understand the purpose of stackoverflow, read the faq first please

Comment: @peter I'm now more clear about this question, and Andrew answers me with `.map` that I didn't know before, can you please  vote-it up ? I can no longer ask questions in stackoverflow because of this question.

Comment: i didn't vote you down you know, but i'll give you a +,in the future please search first, try thing out second and only then ask a question after having checked if it's not allready asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
ex = ["el01", "el02", "el03", "el04"]
ex.each do |str|
  # do with str, e.g., printing each element:
  puts str
end
```

Using `for` in Ruby is not recommended, as it simply calls `each` and it does not introduce a new scope.

However, if your intent is to change each element in the array, you should use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
ex = ["el01", "el02", "el03", "el04"]
ex.map do |str|
  str.upcase
end
#=> ["EL01", "EL02", "EL03", "EL04"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this:

```
for item in ex
    #do something with the item here
    puts item
end
```

A more Ruby idiomatic way to do it is:

```
ex.each do |item|
    #do something with the item here
    puts item
end
```

Or, you can do it in one line:

```
ex.each {|item| puts item}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ruby way is to use the `#each` method of lists. And several other classes have `#each`, too, like Ranges. Therefore you will almost never see a for loop in ruby.